# How to inject a Validator in the JUnit test of a SpringBoot-based service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, hibernate-validator

I'm building a SpringBoot CRUD application based on a REST controller calling a Spring Service. The POJO received have validation-related annotations (including custom validators) and the actual validations are triggered inside the Service (see below).

Everything works perfectly fine in a SpringBoot execution.

I now need to build relevant *unit* test cases for my Service i.e I do *not* want to start an application server via a SpringBootRunner.

Below is my Patient class with validation-related annotations.

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Patient {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @NotEmpty(message = "patient.name.mandatory")
  private String name;
  @Past(message = "patient.dateOfBirth.inThePast")
  @NotNull(message = "patient.dateOfBirth.mandatory")
  private Date dateOfBirth;
  private boolean isEmergency;

  // [...]
}
```

This is the Service called by SpringBoot's REST controller.

```
@Service
@Validated
public class PatientService {
  @Autowired
  private PatientRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  private Validator validator;

  public Patient create(Patient patient) {
    if (! patient.isEmergency()) {
      validator.validate(patient);
      // then throw exception if validation failed
    }
    // [...]
  }
}
```

And here is my JUnit test.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(ModalityTestConfiguration.class)
public class PatientServiceTest {
  @InjectMocks
  private PatientService service;

  @MockBean
  private PatientRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  private Validator validator;

  @Test
  public void invalidEmptyPatientNoEmergency() {
    Patient p = new Patient();
    Patient result = null;
    try {
      result = service.create(p); // validations must fail -> exception
      assert(false);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
      // Execution should get here to verify that validations are OK
      assert(result != null);
      assert(e.getConstraintViolations() != null);
      assert(e.getConstraintViolations().size() != 0);
      // [...]
    } catch (Exception e) {
      assert(false);
    }
}
```

Just in case, here is the REST controller (not relevant I think as not related to the JUnit test)

```
@RestController
public class PatientController {
  @Autowired
  private PatientService patientService;

  @PostMapping("/patients")
  Patient createPatient(@RequestBody Patient patient) {
    return (patientService.create(patient));
  }
```

My problem is that **the Validator in my Service is always null**.

- I have tried creating a dedicated configuration file with a validator bean

```xml
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

and linking the configuration to the Test case

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/modality-test-config.xml"})
```

- I have tried to define a local @Bean for the Validator
- I have played around with and without @Autowire
- I have changed the @RunWith

I'm sure it must be a minor detail somewhere but I just don't seem to get a not-null validator inside the JUnit test of the Service.

**UPDATE**

Here is the TestConfiguration class I have added following TheHeadRush comment.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class ModalityTestConfiguration {

    @Bean("validator")
    public Validator validator() {
        return (Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator());
    }
}
```

I have also added the corresponding @Import annotation in the Test class above.

Still no luck: the Validator field remains null in both the Test class and in the Service. Also, the breakpoint in the TestConfiguration class doesn't seem to get called.

Comment: Create a `@TestConfiguration` class that provides your `Validator` bean.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I've tried with no success:

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the `@TestConfiguration` class into your post.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Done now. Apologies for previous super-short-comment that was supposed to include more information but was submitted after pressing Enter (no line breaks in comments it seems).

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the return of the `validator` method, debug the spec and see if the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Partial good news: if I use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner with Autowired properties then the elements _are_ injected and I get into the TestConfiguration calls. The concern is that the test starts the full SpringBoot (with DB connection and everything) so it has become a long integration test. If I use the MockitoJunitRunner then the Mock repository is injected but not the validator.

Comment: FYI I haven't found a way to inject a Validator so I've solved the issue by getting a new Validator every time via Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator(). I assume (hope) it's a Singleton so there won't be a terrible performance issue; if there is, I'll find another way.